# Css files of liberary can not be load

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to add Zurb Foundation framework to my theme library file. However, when I add the following code to my library, the java script file load without any probleme or difficulty but css files only can not be load.

I would be grateful to hear what is the problem with the code and what is the right way to load a css of the library?

This is my theme folder structure (Zurb Foundation folder location):

```
|-Theme Name
|  |-includes
|  |  |-foundation
|  |  |  |-css
|  |  |  |-js
```

Library file:

```
foundation:
  version: 6.x
  css:
    includes/foundation/css/app.css: {}
    includes/foundation/css/foundation.css: {}
    includes/foundation/css/foundation.min.css: {}
  js:
    includes/foundation/js/app.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.min.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/jquery.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/what-input.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

[theme_name].info.yml file:

```
name: Theme Name
type: theme
core: 8.x
base theme: classy
libraries:
  - Theme Name/foundation
  - Theme Name/global
```

And finally, I uncheckmark **Aggregate CSS** and  **Aggregate JavaScript files** boxes in performance, flush caches and clear my browser cache.

screenshot of Source page:
[image]
As you can see the javascript files load witout any problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets)

> You may notice the 'theme' key for css which is not present for js. This indicates the style type the css file belongs to.
>
> You can set CSS weights with 5 different levels of styling:

- **base** key assigns a weight of CSS_BASE = -200
- **layout** key assigns a weight of CSS_LAYOUT = -100
- **component** key assigns a weight of CSS_COMPONENT = 0;
- **state** key assigns a weight of CSS_STATE = 100
- **theme** key assigns a weight of CSS_THEME = 200

> This is defined by the SMACSS standard. So here if you specify theme
>   it means that the CSS file contains theme related styling which is
>   pure look and feel. More info here. You **cannot use** other keys as these
>   will cause strict warnings.

In your case you can use key **theme**

```
foundation:
  version: 6.x
  css:
    theme:
      includes/foundation/css/app.css: {}
      includes/foundation/css/foundation.css: {}
      includes/foundation/css/foundation.min.css: {}
  js:
    includes/foundation/js/app.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.min.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/jquery.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/what-input.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

Comment: I add key theme but Nothing has changed.

Comment: try clear cache. And css file add to head. js default add to bottom of body.